# Как изменить operationId в Swagger?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, swagger

Обновился до Core 2.2
В Swagger появилась проблема с operationId.

Например:

```
GET /Api/User/List
```

operationId был **ApiUserListGet**

Сейчас же просто **List**

Как сделать такой *operationId*?

Проблема в том что если есть методы одинаковые (GET /Api/Phone/List) то он пишет например `List2` и т.д.

Comment: А у вас установлен Route атрибут у контролера ?

Comment: @EvgeniyZ у каждого контроллера только так [HttpGet("List")]

Comment: У контроллера или метода? Судя по `List` - все же метода. Поясню вам свою догадку. Swagger собирает все публичные методы, беря за основу путь, который устанавливается маршрутом. Я лично на своем сайте имею два API, у одного методы помечены как устаревшие, они оба похожи друг на друга и имеют схожие методы. Только один (устаревший) у меня помечен как `[Route("api/agent")][Obsolete] public class OldAgentApi : Controller`,  другой `[Route("api/v2/[controller]")] public class AgentController : Controller`, как видите пути указаны разные и Swagger успешно их [определил](https://evgeniy-z.ru/docs/).

Comment: @EvgeniyZ Если я тоже полный путь ([Route("api/v2/[controller]")] ) укажу как хочу, тогда будет все хорошо. У меня просто очень очень много методов и они уже завязаны и менять дело сложное. Но просто с Swashbuckle.AspNetCore 1.0 все работает как надо, а на версии 4.0.1 работает совсем не так как раньше, скорее всего они изменили что-то. В документации не нашел решения

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Нашел:
Explicit OperationIds now required:
As per the Swagger spec, operationIds MUST be unique and SHOULD follow common programming conventions. In previous versions, Swashbuckle attempted to generate these values but this has proved increasingly problematic. As a result, this behavior has been removed and the action name or (optionally) the route name is used instead. So, API developers are now responsible to ensure the uniqueness of these values. See the readme topic for more details.